# How to play in-game sounds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a simple game by using Pygame and I want to add some in-game sounds repeating during play time. However, the game stops running when I apply those codes:

```
def in-gameSounds():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    startTime = time.time()
    theFile = 'Sounds/gameSound.ogg'
    theFile2 = 'Sounds/gameSound2.ogg'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(theFile)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    playing = True
    while playing == True:
            while time.time() <= startTime + 457:
                time.sleep(0.01)
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            pygame.mixer.music.load(theFile2)
            while time.time() > startTime + 457 and time.time() <= startTime+ 3752:
                time.sleep(0.01)
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            for click in pygame.event.get():
                if click.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if click.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        playing = False
            startTime -= 3752
    pygame.mixer.quit()
```

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part3/) on playing music and sound effects in `pygame`.

Comment: How exactly does the game stop running? Does it fail to launch? Does it freeze? Does it crash with a specific error? This will help us help you. Thanks.

Comment: It says that "python.exe is not responding".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing pygame.mixer.music.play() an argument of -1? That makes it loop indefinitely. From there you can use the pause(), unpause(), and rewind() methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `pygame.mixer.init()` followed by `pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)` in the top of your program instead of putting it in a function. Since a value of -1 one inside of the `()` will mean an infinite loop, the music will continuously play unless forced to stop via program killing, Ctrl-C, etc.

```
pygame.mixer.init()                         # Initiate pygame.mixer
pygame.mixer.music.load('song_name_here')   # Load song to play
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)          # Change volume
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)                 # Play song infinitely
```